# Ограничение обрабатываемых символов (Си)

Tags: c

Добрый день!

Имеется программа, получающая на вход символы и переводящая их в шестнадцатеричную систему. Как можно изменить код так, чтобы программа обрабатывала лишь определённое кол-во символов?

Например: при n = 3, программа получая на вход "Hello", обрабатывала бы только Hel.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char in[255];
    char out[255];
    int len;
    char ch = '\0';


    fgets(in, sizeof(in), stdin);
    len = strlen(in);

    if(in[len-1]=='\n') in[--len] = ch;

        for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)
            {
                sprintf(out+i*2, "%x", in[i]);
            }
            printf("%s\n", out);
}
```

P.S: нельзя использовать string.h и malloc

Comment: делайте цикл не до len а до меньшего из значений n или len

Comment: Работает, спасибо.

Comment: *"нельзя использовать string.h"*--  а что у вас тогда делает `strlen()`?

Comment: Нельзя инклюдить string.h. Ошибся

Comment: Во-первых, он у вас неявно инклудится из `stdlib.h`. Во-вторых, вы всё равно использыете `strlen()`. В третьих, использовать строковые функции можно и не подключив `string.h`, это же C, а не C++. И в четвёртых, на будущее - формальный запрет на `malloc()` во многих случаях обходится использованием `alloca()` :-)

Answer (score 2):

> нельзя использовать string.h и malloc

А это тогда что?

```
len = strlen(in);
```

Или требование не использовать `string.h` касается только явного включения этого заголовка в исходник? А случаи неявного включения, или использования строковых функций без объявлений - допустимы?

Но в любом случае здесь можно обойтись и без `strlen()`:

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < n && in[i] > 0x0D; i++ )
{
    printf( "%02X", in[i] );
}
```

Comment: А что делать со строкой "H♀♂lo"? :) Она у вас обработается неверно... Или со слишком длинной строкой, не влезшей в `in`, при `N` еще большем? (это намек :))

Comment: *А что делать со строкой "H♀♂lo"?* -i]`- очевидно, изменить условие проверки `in[i]`. *Или...* -- варианты разные могут быть. Пусть автор вопроса сам над ними думает.

Answer (score 1):

Так сойдет? Никаких строковых функций, минимум переменных...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char in[255];

    const int N = 3;   // Ваше ограничение

    fgets(in, sizeof(in), stdin);

    for(char * c = in; *c && (*c != '\n') && (c - in < N); c++)
    {
        printf("%02X", *c);
    }
}
```